# Function App App files -requirements.psd1

Tags: azure-functions, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

When a function app is created (using the Powershell runtime), it comes with a requirements.psd1 files in the "App files" which has this content

```
This file enables modules to be automatically managed by the Functions service.
See https://aka.ms/functionsmanageddependency for additional information.
@{
# For latest supported version, go to 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az'.
# To use the Az module in your function app, please uncomment the line below.
# 'Az' = '6.'
}
```

the line AZ=6. is commented, is there a way that this line can be uncommented at deployment time using ARM template or Azure Powershell?

Comment: Found your question while building Bicep templates. Wondering if it works from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can't do that during the deployment, the workaround is to update the file after deployment via the [Kudu API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#vfs) in poweshell.

Store the new `requirements.psd1` with the path e.g. `C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\requirements.psd1` in local.

```
# This file enables modules to be automatically managed by the Functions service.
# See https://aka.ms/functionsmanageddependency for additional information.
#
@{
    # For latest supported version, go to 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az'. 
    # To use the Az module in your function app, please uncomment the line below.
     'Az' = '6.*'
}
```

Then use the script below.

```
$appsvWebAppName = "<functionapp-name>"
$resourceGroupName = "<group-name>"

$resource = Invoke-AzResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName "$appsvWebAppName/publishingcredentials" -Action list -ApiVersion 2018-02-01 -Force

$username = $resource.Properties.publishingUserName
$password = $resource.Properties.publishingPassword
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username, $password)))
$userAgent = "powershell/1.0"


$apiUrl = "https://$appsvWebAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/requirements.psd1"
$filePath = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\requirements.psd1"
$headers = @{
    'Authorization' = 'Basic ' + $base64AuthInfo
    'If-Match' = '*'
}
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers $headers -UserAgent $userAgent -Method PUT -InFile $filePath -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
```